# Is it possible to simulate the new MacBook Pro notch display somehow?

Tags: xcode, macos

I'd like to check an app works OK without having to lose all profit from it by buying a new MacBook Pro! Or two even; one 14" and one 16"!

Whilst it seems unlikely there will be a problem, some apps have had issues (e.g. iTerm2)

Comment: Xcode should include a simulator, just like they do for the TouchBar.

Answer (score 0):

You can download and install this projecT:

https://github.com/megabitsenmzq/Notch-Simulator

Comment: This only simulates the notch visually, and not the related new API's like this one: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsscreen/3882915-auxiliarytopleftarea